# Removing duplicates in Python

Tags: python

My program so far

```
def RemoveDuplicates(text):
    result=[]
    used=set()
    for char in text:
        if char not in used:
            used.add(char)
            result.append(char)
    return ''.join(result)

text=input('Enter some text: ')
print(join(result))
```

I'm a beginner to Python so this is a quite difficult task for me. I know this doesn't add up, but where have I made the mistake?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're ever calling RemoveDuplicates in your sample code.

Comment: Well, Python doesn't have any magic. You can't write random stuff and hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You've never actually *called* your `RemoveDuplicates()` function.

Replace:

```
text=input('Enter some text: ')
print(join(result))
```

with:

```
print(RemoveDuplicates(input("Enter some text:" )))
```

Comment: @user1248367: It *could* be written even in one line, but with worse performance. The function seems good.

Comment: Oh there are plenty of ways to write that shorter -- in one or two lines, in fact. But it's homework and what you have works, so I'd turn it in.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers: if you're using Python 2, you need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Answer (score 0):

A few things here:

1. You defined the function `RemoveDuplicates`, but never actually call it.
2. You use a `set()`, but then check for duplicates manually. A set, by definition, will get rid of duplicates automatically.
3. You haven't told us what you are actually trying to accomplish. Do that, then we can help you more.

Comment: Although since he is trying to remove duplicate characters from a string, a set() would not maintain sort order

Comment: Sorry. I want the program to ask the user to enter some text. The output should be the text with duplicates removed.

Text entered: "Stackoverflow", Output: Stackoverflw

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `set` is being used manually because it's necessary to retain the order of the original text.

Comment: I think the `if char not in used:` test is still redundant, which is the point @jwd was tring to make.

Comment: @Marius: Well, the test isn't needed in order to do `used.add(char)`, but it **is** still needed for the `result.append(char)`. I was misunderstanding at first.

Answer (score 0):

Your function looks okay to me, although I'm no expert. I think the problem lies in the fact that you're not actually calling it anywhere. Try calling it like this: `print(RemoveDuplicates(text))`.

Answer (score 0):

One small problem is that you forgot to call your function!
Additionally, if you're using Python 2.x the user input needs to be collected using `raw_input`.

Two small fixes and your code works fine:

```
def RemoveDuplicates(text):
    result=[]
    used=set()
    for char in text:
        if char not in used:
            used.add(char)
            result.append(char)
    return ''.join(result)

text = raw_input('Enter some text: ')
print(RemoveDuplicates(text))
```

Comment: raw_input is python 2.  It was renamed to `input` for python 3.x.